# Как получить данные из бд с кодировкой ANSI?

Tags: php, sql, yii2, кодировка, ansi

С базы данных данные приходят в кодировке ANSI
Английские слова и цифры - приходят корректно. Кириллица приходит как ????????(знаки вопросов)
Но есть подозрение, что charset => windows-1251 вообще игнорируется (пробовал вписать туда разное - не выходит) Можете указать на ошибку в коде?

Вот так подключаюсь

```
<?php
    $db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => 'dblib:host=192.111.11.111;dbname=db',
    'username' => 'us',
    'password' => 'pas',
    'charset' => 'microsoft-1251',
                         ]);
              
    $result = $db->createCommand("EXECUTE get :prod")
              ->bindValue(':prod_sn',$serial)
              ->queryAll();
     ?>
```

Comment: Ты-же сам указываешь что тебе нужна кодировка в CP1251 кириллице `'charset' => 'utf-8',` исправит ошибку

Comment: пробовал - не помогло :(

Comment: Какая кодировка таблицы в БД?

Comment: кодировка бд - ANSI

Comment: Заглянул в документацию, правильная кодировка указывается как `utf8`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html  Кодировку БАЗЫ можно посмотреть `SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database` отдельной таблицы через `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`

Comment: `кодировка бд - ANSI` ну тогда тебе надо просто перекодировать базу в `utf8` и перезалить таблицы. у тебя данные ломаться на вводе информации в  базу, а не на выводе.

Comment: Я даже скажу что и обычный utf8 уже технический немного отстаёт. В реалиях 21го века, уже многие перешли на `utf8mb4` для поддержания разных возможных мультибайт символов.

Comment: это в идеале - да
но там огромная база - к которой у меня элементарно нет доступа и тем более там что-то перезаписывать

проблема кроется в самом подключении. если с sqlsrv срабатывало, то просто как-то переписать надо - но как - за этим я здесь

Comment: Если-бы всё шло идеально )) Кодировка Yii utf8 всё что тебе остаётся делать это подключаться именно  как `utf8` а CP-1251 конвертировать уже в запросах. `SELECT column1, CONVERT(column2 USING utf8)
FROM my_table 
WHERE my_condition;`  Вот прям такого супер магического способа что-бы прям на соединии менять - нету.

Comment: Просто в `'charset' => 'microsoft-1251'` ты указываешь именно кодировку соединения PHP с базой. А вот все поля что приходят тебе из базы надо конвертировать уже ручками. Остаётся только или выбирать поля из базы бинарным способом через `CAST(cp1251column AS BINARY) cp1251column`  потом через iconv конвертировать CP1251 в UTF8 или заставить MySQL делать это за тебя. Первый вариант делает нагрузку на сайт, второй делает нагрузку на MySQL . Это уже зависит от того как важно соотношение нагрузки на БД к нагрузке на сайт.